# How to flush a list of data immediately to the database using Repository?

Tags: java, database, spring, repository

I'm using JavaSpring and during the Job's process I'm doing per user I want to save and flush a list of records that I'm getting to the database before the process is handle with the next user.

```
listOfUser.foreach{var list=process(it)
  //now the code for save of the list to the repo suppose to come
     ........
   }
```

One solution I was thinking about is to take the list and use forEach and saveAndFlush (for repo) for each record, but the problems that it might take extra time what I don't want.

```
 list.foreach{ repo.saveAndFlush(it)}
```

Second solution is to take the list and use save method for list (for repo) and then use the flush method of repo.

```
repo.save(list)
repo.flush()
```

I would like to see if you guys have different solutions for me or thinking that one of the solution I suggested are good enough for my case

Thank you

Comment: i tried to use both solutions but non of them is doing the job and showing the new "records" on the database

Comment: Im using @Transaction on the function, maybe this is why its not working?